# Need help with this limit expression: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\left(e^{x/(x+1)}(1-x)+e\cdot x\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\left(e^{x/(x+1)}(1-x)+e\cdot x\right)$$

Without L'Hôpital's rule. What I've done:
$$e - \lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\left(-e^{x/(x+1)}\cdot x+e\cdot x\right) = e - \lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}\left(x\left(e -e^{x/(x+1)}\right)\right)$$
Even though I don't know how to continue here, the weird part is that Mathematica tells me the last limit expression is equal to $e$, which would mean the original expression becomes $0$. Although if I input the original expression into Mathematica, I get the value $2e$ which makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left(x\left(e -e^{\dfrac{x}{x+1}}\right)\right) = e\left(x\left(1 -e^{-\dfrac{1}{x+1}}\right)\right) = e \dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{x+1}}-1}{-\dfrac{1}{x+1}}\dfrac{x}{x+1} \to e (e^x)'|_{x=0}= e$

Comment: Thank you, there's one problem remaining though. This gets me $e-e = 0$. While I'm supposed to get the answer $2e$. But thank you, that was very helpful!

Comment: @XMLParsing Recheck your simplification, you should get $e+ \lim\cdots$, so the result is indeed $2e$

Comment: Hmm, one question: When $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$ how come $\dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{x+1}}-1}{-\dfrac{1}{x+1}}$ goes to $1$ and not $\infty$? I know about the common limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$ but that's $0$, not $\infty$

Comment: @XMLParsing as you write $\dfrac{e^h-1}{h} \to 1$ when $h\to 0$, now take $h = -\dfrac{1}{x+1}$